# Поиск запятых в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Мне нужно регулярное выражение, которое находило бы все запятые в строке. Если их больше 3 то...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\,/` и функция preg_match_all

Comment: Экранировать в регулярных выражениях нужно только [*специальные метасимволы*](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.meta.php), запятая к ним не относится.

Answer (score 1):

> Если их больше 3 то...

можно обойтись без регулярок:

```
$text = ',,,,';

if (count(explode(',', $text)) > 4 ) { // 4 части = 3 запятые
    // тут выполняется код, если в $text больше 3 запятых
}
```

Comment: вот это реально плохой код. А если текст мегабайтный? докупить планку? а если он ещё побольше?

Comment: @KoVadim, с той же самой вероятностью я могу утверждать, что текст там не мегабайтный, а всего 1000 символов, например.

Comment: утверждайте. От этого код лучше не становиться.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения количества вхождений определённой подстроки в строке можно использовать уже имеющиеся возможности PHP — [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr-count.php):

> `substr_count` — Возвращает число вхождений подстроки

[PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/nRg06O):

```
$s = "Один, два, три, четыре, пять";
echo substr_count($s, ','); // => 4
```

Если же необходимо подсчитать количество запятых в каком-то неизвестном контексте (перед буквой, после цифры и т.д.), тогда необходимо использовать регулярное выражение и использовать в функции [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php):

> preg_match_all — Выполняет глобальный поиск шаблона в строке
>   Возвращает количество найденных вхождений шаблона (которое может быть и нулем) либо *FALSE*, если во время выполнения возникли какие-либо ошибки.

Пример: найти все запятые, после которых нет цифры:

```
$cnt = preg_match_all('~,(?!\d)~', '15,50 руб., 16,70 руб.', $matches);
echo $cnt; // => 1
```

[Ещё одно PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/p775iP).